# Not secure error in the Edit Profile - Applications page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, ssl, se-applications

If you are authorized for any applications related to the Stack Exchange sites, it will list the details in the **Application** menu under the **Edit Profile & Settings** tab in the main site and **Settings** tab in the per-site meta.

In the **Application** page, I'm getting the **Connection is Not Secure** error for the `http://` images used as the icons in that page.

In plain text:

> Parts of this page are not secure (such as images).

[image: SSL error]

The `http://` images in the page, can be update with `https://`

---

**Update:**

In my Applications page, the following two image files caused the error:

> `https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATDFd.png`  - Stack Exchange API Documentation image
>   `https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRnbB.png`  - Winter Bash image